# Is there a special name for the block currently at the head of the chain?

Tags: blockchain, block, terminology, height

Just as we have the genesis block which is block 0, is there a special name for the block currently at the head of the chain? Obviously such a block would be observer dependent and never absolute but I am curious all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bitcoin source code refers to it as the 'tip,' e.g., `UpdateTip`, `SetTip`, `ConnectTip`. It's sometimes referred to as the latest block; that's not totally accurate, since the latest block is not always the tip.

Comment: This is more what I was looking for. "Latest block" seems to imply more finality than what exists in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing formal, but "latest block" pretty much describes it.